# reading excel to a python data frame starting from row 5 and including headers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, import

I have an excel workbook that runs some vba on opening which refreshes a pivot table and does some other stuff.

Then I wish to import the results of the pivot table refresh into a dataframe in python for further analysis.

```py
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Users\cb\Machine_Learning\cMap_Joins.xlsm')
```

The refreshing and opening of the file works fine. But how do I select the data from the first sheet from say row 5 including header down to last record n.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use pandas' ExcelFile [`parse`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.ExcelFile.parse.html) method to read Excel sheets, see [io docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files):

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:\Users\cb\Machine_Learning\cMap_Joins.xlsm')

df = xls.parse('Sheet1', skiprows=4, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

*`skiprows` will ignore the first 4 rows (i.e. start at row index 4), and several [other options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.ExcelFile.parse.html).*

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer is old (as discussed in comments of the accepted answer).
Now the preferred option is using [pd.read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). For example:

```
df = pandas.read_excel('C:\Users\cb\Machine_Learning\cMap_Joins.xlsm'), skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers skip the header together with the first 4 rows. To include the header, `skiprows` should "skip" over it.

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', skiprows=range(1, 5))
```

or

```py
with pd.ExcelFile('Book1.xlsx') as f:
    df = f.parse('Sheet1', skiprows=range(1,5))
```

should do the job.