# define start of a pandas dataframe skipping nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, skip

I'am reading a excel whose I want to start several rows after nan values:

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
Code
```

I am doing in this way:

```
for data in range(len(df)):
   try:
      if 'Code' in df.iloc[data,0]:
      df = df.iloc[data:,:]
   except:
      passs
```

but in this way i miss other parsing errors

I'm tryin this to:

```
if pd.isna(df.iloc[data,0]):
    pass
if 'Code' in str(df.iloc[data,0]):
    df = df.iloc[data:,:]
```

But i get:

```
argument of type 'float' is not iterable in the 'Code' line
```

Any help solving this more efficientlty

Comment: is this what you want? `df[df['col'].notnull()]`

Comment: is the `Code` value in the same row for each spreadsheet? Then you can just use the `skiprows` parameter.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You should really read the Pandas docs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience of using `pandas` but when I looked into documentation for reading_excel, I got below which may help you to skip `NaN` values.

you can pass below params while reading excel

1. na_values
2. keep_default_na
3. na_filter

you can get more information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Skiprows will be helpful to skip some rows and read data while reading from the excel ..

```
df_can = pd.read_excel('https://....Canada.xlsx',
                   sheet_name='Canada by Citizenship',
                   skiprows=range(20),
                   skipfooter=2)
```

Please check this gist for how to read an excel file into pandas dataframe after skipping some rows.

https://gist.github.com/dhamayanthim80/b0d861d7cffe48094f89fd8e05609e17

Sorry if my answer is irrelevant to your question.

[reading excel to a python data frame starting from row 5 and including headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548669/reading-excel-to-a-python-data-frame-starting-from-row-5-and-including-headers)

Please check if this is helpful.