# How do i properly format the excel worksheet in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel Workbook that looks like this:
[image]
when I try to import this sheet into python using the following code:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
xls.sheet_names
ac_char = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = "AC characteristics")
```

the output of the above code is:
[image]
How do I eliminate those NaNs and just display the main columns that have the data?

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the first two rows using `skiprows` and first column using `usecols`:

```py
ac_char = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name="AC characteristics", skiprows=[0,1], usecols=[1:])
```

See also: [reading excel to a python data frame starting from row 5 and including headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548669/reading-excel-to-a-python-data-frame-starting-from-row-5-and-including-headers)

Comment: This only eliminates the rows. How do I eliminate the column NA values?

Comment: I changed the answer to also exclude the first column

Answer (score -1):

The way you have formatted your excel file is whats giving you issues. Pandas likes your data to look like the below data and this should fix majority of your issues, So to reiterate. Remove blank columns and have heading withs the relevant data below. Depends what you want to do. The answer below could be closer to your desired solution depending on your use case of the data.

[image]

Comment: OP asks for a method to read the specific Workbook, not how the Workbook could be modified so that the code works.

Comment: Hi Wouter, hope you are having a good day. I am wondering what exactly his use case is. The way he worded the question leads me to believe he hasn't worked with pandas much so just wanted to clarify basics for him and see if it helps him out